# Why Value(${someVariable}) in (DatabaseName)sCompanion shows error in Flutter?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter

I need to pass some value from `TextField()` in flutter to the database that I create using moor and moor generator in flutter. My database name is Tag, so when I pass the value in each column using:

```
TagsCompanion(
 category: Value(categoryController.text),
 monthly: Value(budget),);
```

It was working fine before but now it shows that Value is not defined in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, by mistake I removed the import moor plugin line.
Just add the following and it should work fine:

import 'package:moor/moor.dart';